# Using requests in python to post to a html form?

Tags: python, post, python-requests

If I were trying to google something, how would I send the data I want to search to be searched? I know you can add it to the url, but I do not want to do this.

Comment: which version of python are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Using the requests library.  You would use the .post method in the same way as the .get method.  Passing in the data as a dictionary to the data parameter of the function.

The quickstart docs describe it here http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

If using urllib or urllib2 the `data` parameter of the urlopen function will `POST` the data to the page rather than `GET` it.

see the docs here http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen

Comment: The OP is asking about how to use the "requests" third-party library.

Comment: oh :) I just thought he meant requests in a general sense.